# msys2 git on windows errors looking for shared object file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, msys2

I am trying to use my msys2 git install (which works 100% from within msys2) from Visual Studio Code, but it errors immediately upon trying. The error I get is:

...`msys2/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Has anyone experienced this? Any fix?

Comment: You might try putting the msys2/bin directory in your PATH environment variable so it can find those libraries.

Comment: For anyone else searching, this can also happen if you've accidentally moved one of the DLLs out of its normal home (e.g. to a redist folder) instead of copying [slaps self]... or otherwise accidentally deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to David Grayson - I was able to get this - The answer is twofold.

1. Ensure that the directory to wherever your code is (repo) is the same as your msys directory (ie. I had mine in `C:/Users/<username>`, but mounted at `/home/<username>` ) So I had to do a mklink from `C:/Users/<username>`to `/home/<username>`.
2. As David said but the `git.exe` into your windows path. For me that is `<basedir>msys2/usr/bin/`

After that everything was working fine.

This was for visual studio code on windows 10 by the way.

Thanks -

---

Another option is to create a batch file and point Code.exe at the batch file for git; ie `git.bat`

```
@echo off
@set "PATH==%PATH%;C:\cmder\vendor\msys2\usr\bin;"
@call "C:\cmder\vendor\msys2\usr\bin\git.exe" %*
```

I like to keep my system portable, that is the reason for this layout.